# Issue regarding shell exec?

Tags: java, apache, shell-exec

Below line is not executing `prog.java` simply it is executing `javac`. How can i execute `prog.java` here?

```
  shell_exec('C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_05\bin\javac C:\Apache24\htdocs\uploads\prog.java ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming **shell_exec** is your method for doing system calls **AND** you have prog.class in the dir specified try:

```
shell_exec('C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_05\bin\java C:\Apache24\htdocs\uploads\prog'
```

Comment: Thank you for replying , but still sir , i am getting this as an output on browser. Usage: java [-options] class [args...] (to execute a class) or java -jar [-options] jarfile [args...] (to execute a jar file) where options include: -hotspot to select the "hotspot" VM If present, the option to select the VM must be first. The default VM is -hotspot. -cp -classpath  set search path for application classes and resources -D= set a system property -verbose